# PHP Validation (SQL) and Redirection

Tags: php, redirect

I am getting a value "ID" from the URL using GET, as follows -

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && (filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))) {
  $colname = $_GET['id'];
}
else
{
$URL="/index.php";
header ("Location: $URL");
exit(); 
}
```

I am then checking if the element of that ID exists in the table, as follows -

```
$query_validate = sprintf("SELECT * from surveys where id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname, "int"));
$result_validate = mysql_query($query_validate, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_validate = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_validate);
$num_validate = mysql_num_rows($row_validate);
if($num_validate==0)
{
$URL="/index.php";
header ("Location: $URL");
exit;   
}
```

The idea is that when I type in the url as http://example.com/surveys?id=1, it loads the first survey, and so on. **If an invalid ID (alphabets, id does not exist in the table, etc) is entered, it should redirect the user back to index.php, this is the basic premise of my code.**

However, even if I go to the URL http://example.com/surveys?id=abc, it loads the page and displays an SQL Syntax error. I know that the header function cannot be invoked after output has been given on to the page, but these 2 checks happen very close to the start and I have ensured there is no output happening there.

Comment: _“and I have ensured there is no output happening there”_ – and what do you think the SQL error message you said you are getting is – if not _output_ …?

Comment: %s means string, %d means integer.. just FYI

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated try using mysqli...

Comment: turn off error_reporting by `error_reporting(0)`

Comment: @Nouphal.M or even better: PDO

Comment: There is no output before the first checks (Isset/Is number) and even they fail @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$num_validate = mysql_num_rows($result_validate);
```

Instead of

```
$num_validate = mysql_num_rows($row_validate);
```

Code:

```
    $query_validate = sprintf("SELECT * from surveys where id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname, "int"));
    $result_validate = mysql_query($query_validate, $conn) or die(mysql_error());       
    $num_validate = mysql_num_rows($result_validate);
    if($num_validate==0)
    {
        $URL="/index.php";
        header ("Location: $URL");
        exit;
    }else{
        $row_validate = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_validate);
    }
```

Comment: Made the change, did not help :(

Comment: add `@ob_start()` in top of the page

Comment: No change :\ Even the very first check is not working, let alone the SQL check

Comment: An SQL Syntax error. Like I said the validation is not happening so it is passing the value "abc" as the "ID". Neither the Number Filter, nor the Isset functions seem to be working...

Comment: The error is "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND active = 'y'' at line 1"

This is the first SQL query that actually handles the functionality of this page. Ideally if the validation was happening, it would never even get to that line :( Thats why I am confused

Comment: And the error happens because the int "ID" is being passed "abc"

Comment: Can we have teamviewer session ? or post that query here

Comment: Teamviewer sounds great! Is there any other place I could talk to you in private?

Comment: Just managed to get it to work! Thank you for the help! (Forgot to update my dependencies!)